# Large image not loading properly?

Tags: html, css, image, image-loading

Never ran into this issue before, I mean we all have obviously, but my techniques to limit the size or compress the image are still causing it to load slow. The image is 150kb roughly. I exported it for web using progressive jpg, yet it still loads a section at a time, basically I don't want to see any whitespace on the first load. The progressive seems to be working however it only targets the first half of the image it seems.

[image]

link to domain so you can test it yourself.
ON PORTFOLIO LINK --------> Ryanstirlingportfolio.ca

Comment: Your link doesn't work. And 150K is not that much.

Comment: Was re-Uploading sorry, exactly 150 is not much at all so it should not be loading choppy I dont get it. Try the link now

Comment: As I can see you have 3 big images to load - coverImage.jpg, logoCover.png, responsiveDesign.jpg and they. No need to have 4500px of width. About 2000px is enough.